# ZF2 How To Include google-site-verification <meta> Tag In Twig View

Tags: symfony, view, twig, meta

I am trying to add

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="WcGeoFJE8eKgXlxMoHRDpJz1bpPFMGh25PK8M-eDlAw" />
```

to the  section within my layout.twig .  I've saved the file and uploaded it to the development version of the web site.  But this HTML isn't being included.

All the other entries within the  section are Twig codes.  Not HTML.  I am unsure if I have a cache issue and the revised version of my layout.twig isn't being loaded or if there is some Twig code I should be using for this  tag?

Comment: i suggest you to try the site verification with the `file HTML verification`procedure. Pro: no cache problem, no php problem etc...

Comment: I use Composer to update the production version of the web site.  If I understand correctly it will remove the .html file used for verification.  I was really hoping this could be accomplished through the layout.twig

Comment: put the html files in the web folder of the symfony2 project as example `./web/googlec1f59ff86d15c795.html`

Comment: Hi @RonPiggott Have you solved? If yes, how?

Comment: I've used the method you recommended.  I accessed the command line "public" directory and created the Google .html verification file.  Composer did not remove the file.

Comment: Hi @RonPiggott can i post my comment as an answer so you can close your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modify the code of your application, I suggest you to proceed to the site verification with the Google file HTML verification procedure.

Simply add the Google files in the web root folder of the project, as example:

```
./web/googlec1f59ff86d15c795.html
```

And commit with your source file. In this manner the deploy procedure don't remove your files.

Another good practice, as suggested by @ Pazi ツ is to act with the DNS configuration (this require you can manage the DNS site configuration).

Hope this help